# Return multiple values from one class to another

Tags: java, swing, inheritance

I need to return several boolean values from one class to another, here's the class that's creating the value :

```
public class Units {

    public static boolean unit1A;

    public static void mainPanel(final JFrame mainMenuFrame){

            unit1A = true;

        }
    }
```

And the class that I want to return the value to

```
public class UnitsTesting{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Units.unit1A);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately because of my poor project design i'm keeping the final JFrame in to switch out my frames when needed, so that needs to stay in, otherwise I would know how to do this.

Edit : For anyone interested looking at this i'm just going to return an array of booleans, as suggested by Ashis Kumar Sahoo.

Comment: Consider making a third class to act as a wrapper class. It could have fields that map to your boolean values. Each field can be set by the method, then the class instance can be returned to the caller.

Comment: This statement, `"Unfortunately because of my poor project design i'm keeping the final JFrame in to switch out my frames when needed,..."`, seems to assume that we understand things not yet explained to us. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please explain the details of your problem.

Comment: Why dont you return an array? "boolean [] unit1 = new boolean[10]" maybe.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Will do, that was just more to give an excuse for why I need to keep it up there.

Comment: @AshisKumarSahoo That would work really well, thank you for the help!